# Accessing POST Data by Index

Tags: php, post, loops

Is there any way to access POST data by index, rather than accessing it through keys? I'd like the following code to work:

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($_POST); $x++)
    echo $x . ": " . $_POST[$x];
```

(Yes, I know that count in the loop is bad, just using it for simplicity)

The problem is that apparently I can't access the $_POST variable by index, it has to be accessed by key. The reason I can't use keys is because I'm going to have variable form data, so there could be more or less in the POST, so I need to be able to loop through a variable number of keys, with variable names.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: To clarify, I was confused because I had previously assumed that PHP arrays behaved almost like C++ enumerations.

Comment: Why not just try it and see? Also, you can always use foreach()

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was under the impression that PHP arrays were like C++ enums, guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreach() instead, it also works on numeric arrays.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val)
    printf("%s: %s\n", $key, $val);
```

Comment: All of the answers were solid, since it was a simple question(my bad), but the code in this one is what I needed to move forward immediately

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to access POST data by index, rather than accessing it through keys?

No, it doesn't have numerical indexes.

> The reason I can't use keys is because I'm going to have variable form data, so there could be more or less in the POST, so I need to be able to loop through a variable number of keys, with variable names.

You can loop through associative arrays. See the documentation of [`foreach`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
  statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key. ":" .$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes and keys are the same thing. The key is either a number (e.g. `$_POST[0]`) or it's a string (e.g. `$_POST['foo']`). It cannot be both. You cannot access `$_POST['foo']` through `$_POST[0]`.

Comment: $_POST might have been altered inbetween. The numeric keys are not reordered in that case. So they may contain gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Technically possible, though `foreach` is superior:

```
$postVals = array_value($_POST);
$postCount = count($_POST);
for($x = 0; $x < $postCount; $x++)
    echo $x . ": " . $postVals[$x];
```